# How to override only the render() function of component-search-result-filer.js to another file of Sitecore SXA?

Tags: sxa

Based on our design requirement there are few modifications i need to do in `render()` function of `component-search-result-filer.js` which is used by checklist filter of Sitecore SXA.

I want to override the function in another js file so that it doesn't gets overwritten on SXA upgrade. The remaining functionality should work as it is.

I tried few options after googling but doesn't work. There always be a syntax problem, not getting it right.

Can someone please provide a sample code to do so.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of options to do that:

#### Clone the Search Theme

Probably the easiest thing to do would be to make a copy of all the base `SearchTheme` script files. These are in the Media Library here: `/sitecore/media library/Base Themes/SearchTheme` - add those files to your own theme and customize the contents as you need too. You would then need to remove the `SearchTheme` from your own sites base themes:

[image]

#### Override the whole object

To access the object, you can use `XA.component.search.facet.resultFilter` - that will return you the object as registered with the `XA` framework. So at that point you *can* reassign a function.

But - the problem you have is that you want to override the `.render()` function, and that is not a function of the `resultFilter` object directly. If you look at the JavaScript file, it is using a `FacetResultsFilterView` object that extends the `XA.component.search.baseView` object. That is the part that contains the render method, so you would effectively have to replace the entire function with your custom version:

```
XA.component.search.facet.resultsfilter = (function ($, document) {
    // add your entire implementation here
} (jQuery, document));
```

Depending on how complex your change is, this might be easier. Both options have pros/cons, but I think that replacing the entire base theme with a custom will probably be more stable and easier to maintain than trying to override the function. Its also pretty quick to do and test.

Comment: Thank you for the reply :)